# Directing a Car to head for a signal by measuring signal strength

Tags: algorithm, arduino

I Have a Car Robot kit, ([Sunfounder Smart Video Car Kit](https://www.sunfounder.com/rpi-car.html))
and as I learn, I want to make it drive to a Beacon.

I know how to measure the signal strength,
I now want to make up an algorithm to direct the car at the beacon.

I came up with several ideas, but i don't think they are the optimal:

- define t - time part - time span for quanta.
- define Q - Quanta - the distance driven by the car in time 't'.
- define P - Power - the signal strength

### Idea 1:

- Assume car is @ (0,0)
- Assume Car heading @ (0,1)
- Drive forward 1Q
- Record A0 = P[T] - P[T-t]
- Drive backward 1Q
- Turn Wheels to (alpha = (constant)) degrees (cause pre-computed/measured angle)
- Drive forward 1Q
- Record A1 = P[T] - P[T-t]
- Axis0 = b0 = (0,1)
- Axis2 = b1 = (cos(alpha), sin(alpha))
- D = A0*b0 + A1*b1
- now i need to drive heading to `D`!

but this feels very slow method.

### Idea2

- Drive forward
- if (dP < 0) drive Backward
- When 'dP ~= 0' // i know i am driving perpendicular to the becon
- turn 90deg right
- if(dP < 0) drive backward

this is a bit better but still aint optimal, as i could make the adjustment long before i got to dP = 0

Additionally, i Can't really make sure i am doing a good 90deg turn,
my car have a turn radius (unlike a Tank bot)

### Third Idea

My third idea aims being close to optimal but i didn't get it right:

Let P - Power of signal
Let D - Distance from beacon

My idea, which involves correcting my angle as i go,
Is that "when heading at the beacon, dP will descent at P(D)' rate,
so i try get there.

just to reduce the computations, i will use D instead of P and try to get D=0

1. CMD = `FORWARD`
2. if dD decrease (d2D < 0) => beacon is in front of me, but not directly.
   so CMD = LAST RIGHT/LEFT CMD
3. if d2D ~= 0 CMD = `FORWARD`
4. **now i am missing something** if CMD=`LEFT`/`RIGHT` && **it's getting worse** CMD = OPPOSITE(CMD)
5. Go To Step 2

I tried simulating that idea, but it got me really nowhere.

can you help me formulate the algorithm please?

[I created an Excel sheet to simulate,
Enter the degree of turn in the CMD column and look at the results.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzdxONG_3wXha3R1eGJoSzNDTVk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Can you calculate the ratio by which the signal intensity change per unit of distance ?!
Like, how much does the intensity change when I move 5cm closer to the beacon.
If you have that, you could "correct angle as you go" when the dP ratio is higher or lower to that given dPRatio.
Because that dPRatio would mean that your are going straight to the beacon !!

Comment: this was my 3rd idea but i didnt get how to formulate it.  and i cant know i was going 5cm (no Inertial sensors) but i can say i was driving for 1 second => Xcm

Comment: It's okay, make some experience, move the car on a straight line toward the beacon an record the dP for a given time, then calculate the target_dP =  dP/time.

Comment: Im assuming the car is moving at a constant speed btw.

Comment: 1sec=>Xcm... depends on acceleration/deceleraton but that wasnt my problem... i even tried generating an excel sheet for simulation...

Comment: What data did you have ?  Signal strength according to distance from beacon ? Because That's the solution to your problem

Comment: yes, the siganl strength is the data i have, but I didn't get how to use it correctly.
i'll later, edit my question with my attempts on it so far .

Comment: target_dP = (dP2 - dP1)/(time2 - time1)